# using elfinder 2.x with java connector

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, elfinder

i am using elfinder 1.2 with my jsp page. but i want to use the its latest version elfinder 2.x  http://elfinder.org/. but this latest version is not working with the old 1.x java connector. can anyone please suggest me how to use it or can provide me the latest connector for it.
https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Using-elFinder-2.x-UI-with-1.x-connector
(here also it is telling that it will not work with old connector)
(sorry for incorrect tagging as there was not tag for elfinder)
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since late 2013 a solution seems to be in process:

https://github.com/bluejoe2008/elfinder-2.x-servlet

It is self-described as:

elfinder-2.x-servlet implements a java servlet for elfinder-2.x connector

I haven't tried it yet (just about to), so I can't vouch for it's completeness or quality.